# How to handle data modification in C# XAML WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

## The issue

Ok Hey guys, my issue is currently trying to think of the best way to edit data that exists in my application written in c# using WPF.

The application is small standalone app that uses XML to store rules on how to interpret hex messages and display it in human readable format.

Currently my app works fine, but i manually crafted the XML, i want to write something in the app that will allow layman users to make their own rule sets and save them to XML.

Now the saving to XML and the handling of the data once edited i am sure i can do, but i'm stumped over the best approach for XML.

Ok for brevity im just giving the general info and exluding some stuff - the classes i'm working with:

### Rulesets

```
public class RuleSet
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string LongName { get; set; }
    public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
    public string Base { get; set; }
    public List<String> IncludedBulletins { get; set; }
    public List<Byte> Bytes { get; set; }

    public RuleSet(string name, string longName, string releaseDate, string @base)
    {
        ReleaseDate = parseDate(releaseDate);

        Name = name;
        LongName = longName;
        Base = @base;
        IncludedBulletins = new List<String>();
        Bytes = new List<Byte>();
    }
}
```

### Bytes

```
public class Byte
{
    public int ID { get; private set; }
    public ReadMode Mode { get; private set; }
    public List<Rule> Rules { get; set; }

    public enum ReadMode
    {
        ASSORTED,
        MULTI,
        SINGLE
    };

    public Byte()
    {
        Rules = new List<Rule>();
    }
}
```

### Rules

```
public class Rule
{
    public bool Active { get; private set; }
    public int BytePos { get; private set; }
    public int NibblePos { get; private set; }
    public int Bit { get; private set; }
    public int EndBit { get; private set; }
    public int Value { get; private set; }
    public int EndValue { get; private set; }
    public string Translation { get; private set; }
    public bool AllLowerBits { get; private set; }

    public Rule()
    {
        Active = false;
        Translation = "RFU";
    }
}
```

Here is an example of the rules we interpret:

[image: CVM Rule]

For Background info this is a Cardholder Verfication Method Rule passed in Banking applications between devices in Hexadecimal format and to interpret it is as described there.

I have a Catalog which is a list of rulesets stored in memory when the application loads initially it loads all the XML and parses it into the objects above which can then be interacted with in the app to provide meaningful information.

What i am struggling with is the best UI display i can make, i have considered a :

1. **Treeview** - with the rulesets and the children being the Bytes, display the properties for a ruleset in the upper part of a form, and when the user clicks on a byte it populated a section listing rules that can be added to with a new button that allows new rules to be made. This would require figuring out how to add a new byte to the treeview and allowing ordering of the treeview so the byte is correctly placed / maneuvered.
2. **Listview** With the rulesets only and data being displayed in a form as before but with tabcontrol for each byte, again this would require figuring out how to add a new byte to the treeview and allowing ordering of the treeview so the byte is correctly placed / maneuvered.
3. **Something else you guys can suggest?**

If anyone has any examples or links to tutorials for the needed things in the list or a better suggestion and examples that would be great I'm largely paralyzed trying to think of the best way to handle this data.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to https://ux.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Which is the format of the document that describes those rules? A table, because it's clear and easy to search and interpret. I think a table might be a good starting point also for your editor (of course it's interactive then it will be even better) but don't forget that an editor is both useful to edit and to search/scan/read the rules...

Comment: So possibly a DataGrid?

Comment: I'd rather not, I imagine (but I don't have any idea about the complexity of your ruleset) a small grid without the "heavyness" of a true DataGrid component. I'd probably love to click the cells to iterate through their possible states (nothing, x, 0, 1) and eventually Excel style copy (drag cell corner to the right/left to set the same value to multiple cells). IMHO you should **not** expose the model you're using, Its fields look like an implementation detail, too far from what I see in the table, if this editor has to be used by someone without programming knowledge then it should be as...

Comment: No I agree my intention is to handle the generation of the complexity for the model  automatically in the backgroun when a user interacts on the main view.

I don't think an end user would understand why i have start and end bits or something like that for example so it would be hidden, i just really care about how many bytes there are in the rule, which is a table for each if it is this then (which maybe suggests the treeview and then a table for each with meta data editable above the table) but the problem is that a table wouldn't cover all of the data needed without another layer imo.

Comment: ...similar as possible to the image you linked (obviously little bit more complex because of some "details" are explained in plain text). However this is to edit a SINGLE BYTE, overall structure is made by multiple rules with multiple bytes, I like the column view in the macOS Finder (first colum for the rule list, second column the list of bytes for the selected rule, third column...what you have in the image). As alternative even a simple collapsible list https://material-ui.com/demos/expansion-panels/. Each rule is a list item, you expand it and you edit its content...

Comment: ....Even better...life with WPF is easy then a master-details view works pretty well. See for example https://medium.com/gone-remote/case-study-master-detail-pattern-revisited-86c0ed7fc3e (all linked examples are for material design, obviously not the best match for a Windows application but the very same layout can be applied to an Office-like UI)

Comment: Thanks @AdrianoRepetti i will have a look at these suggestions

Comment: If you have some time you should really post this on UX (just remove the code...it's not relevant there but to describe the hierarchy) and include one or two mocks of what you're thinking about. I'm sure someone there will come with some pretty good suggestion.